# django EAV filtering

Tags: django, entity-attribute-value

I have the following models.

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductAttribute(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField('Product')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    property = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)
```

I need to be able to select products based on a given category, and a given attribute.

For example, if I have the product "Blender", I want to select all blenders within a given category, with a given attribute (such as brand = black & decker).